# MIPS' stack causes my brain to overflow

Tags: c, assembly, stack, mips, callstack

I absolutely cannot understand MIPS' stack. Space on the stack is allocated by subtracting the *$sp* register, the stack grows on the direction of the program, when it grows too much it overflows by overwriting (or at least trying to) the program. Once the function is executed, I must remove the stack by adding the same value I've subtracted first. This is all fine to me. I was told, though, that when I'm saving arguments I must allocate four spaces, corresponding to the four first arguments (*$a0-$a3*), and never use them (as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253977(v=vs.80).aspx)). Why? Also, when I'm building the stack, I must save extra arguments. Should I save the "not extra" arguments too? *e.g.* the assembly of this C program:

```
void f (int x, int y, int z) {
    int array[5], a, b;

    if (x >= y && x != z)
        g(x+1, y+2, z+3, 4, 5);
    else
        h(x-1, y-2, z-3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

    while (z != 0)
        x++
}
```

Should I save *$a0-$a3*  on their respective stack positions? Should I save them in *$s0-$s3*? If I didn't have the *while* part, should I **not** save them?

Comment: The page you have linked is describing a Microsoft-specific calling convention. It's not the *only* way to use the stack on MIPS CPUs.

Comment: Uh, you don't need to allocate any stack-space in C. C does not, in fact, require a stack. You declare variables with automatic storage duration, the compiler does the rest. Also, +1 for braindamaged Microsoft calling conventions.

Comment: @EOF I'm sorry, what I meant was how the assembly of that C program would be.

Comment: be concerned with accessing stack yourself when writing assembly code. Otherwise, don't bother and let compiler take care of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [System V ABI for MIPS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf)?  I don't know whether it exactly matches the Microsoft spec you're looking at, but it's rather detailed.  As for "why", the answer ultimately boils down to "because that's what allows automated tools like debuggers to reconstruct stack frames from data dumps".  Nobody is forcing you to use any particular ABI if you don't want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a convention that the arguments are passed this way. If you write a program and one of your functions is calling another function also written by you you may also decide to pass all arguments on the stack (instead of $a0-$a3) or do anything different...

However when you call a function not written by you (for example a function generated by a C compiler) or your function is called by such a function you have to assume that the function not written by you behaves like it is described here.

> that when I'm saving arguments I must allocate four spaces, corresponding to the four first arguments ($a0-$a3) and never use them (as stated here). Why?

Early MIPS processors were designed for high-end computers so the main objective behind these conventions was speed and not usability.

I was just thinking about this "strange" convention: There are many cases when this convention will generate the fastest possible code. So this is the reason.

> Should I save the "not extra" arguments too?

You may do this; however the function you call will ignore the data stored there.

When writing an own compiler (I already did) it should be much easier when you DO store the "not-extra arguments" on the stack - so this could be a reason to do it.

Answer (score 2):

MIPS calling conventions from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS)

> The most commonly used[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS) calling convention for 32 bit MIPS is the O32[2] ABI which passes the first four arguments to a function in the registers $a0-$a3; subsequent arguments are passed on the stack. Space on the stack is reserved for $a0-$a3 in case the callee needs to save its arguments, but the registers are not stored there by the caller. The return value is stored in register $v0; a second return value may be stored in $v1.

You can modify the `$t0`,...`$t9` registers without saving them on the stack, but they can be modified by any functions your code calls. If you need to use `$s0`,...,`$s7`, you must save them on the stack and restore them before returning.

Answer (score 1):

- [MIPS Call Convention](http://www.cs.umb.edu/cs641/MIPscallconvention.html)

Here are links from popular answer on the close thread:

- UWisc Madison CS 354 [MIPS conventions](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-2/beyond354/conventions.html)
- [Chapter 3 MIPS Assembly Language](http://cherry.cs.nccu.edu.tw/~whliao/cod/lect4.pdf)
- UMD CS 311 [Understanding the Stack](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)
- UWash Seattle CSE 410 [MIPS Calling Conventions Summary](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse410/09sp/examples/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf)
- Wikipedia [Frame pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_pointer#Structure)

Taken from: [Frame Pointer Explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194339/frame-pointer-explanation)